# How to keep transformation result for all subsequent stages in reactor

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Let's say I have a Reactor stream that consists of 4 stages:

```
Mono.just(event)
.map(this::map1)
.map(this::map2)
.map(this::map3)
.map(this::map4)
```

I want the result of `this::map1` be accessible by `this::map2, this::map3 and this::map4` stages.
Is there any simple way to do this with Reactor?

Comment: Have you checked the [Context](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context) functionality in Reactor? That can probably help you to make information from previous steps to future steps.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo, yes, I checked it, but I couldn't find a way to populate context with transformation result. The only way I found is to populate it with static data(e.g. some constant )

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo How so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would merge your map1, map2, map3 and map4, in a single map function, since the 4 functions depend on one another

But if you insist on using 4 seperate functions, you could pass the context along the reactive stream using a [tuple](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/function/Tuple2.html), for example :

```
private Tuple2<String, HashMap> map3(Tuple2<String, HashMap> inputTuple) {
        String input = inputTuple.getT1();
        HashMap context = inputTuple.getT2();
        // mapping example
        String result = input + context.get("result1") +  "mappingExample";
        context.put("result3", result);
        return Tuples.of(result, context);
    }
```

Or just a simple map that holds all your results, for example :

```
private HashMap<String, String> map3(HashMap<String, String> input) {
    String result3 = input.get("result2") + input.get("result1");
    input.put("result3", result3);
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way of solving this is considering that you need to introduce some sort of "boundary" around `map1`. This can be achieved by a `flatMap`:

```
Mono.just(event)
    .map(this::map1)
    .flatMap(v1 -> Mono.just(v1)
        .map(v2 -> map2(v2, v1))
        .map(v3 -> map3(v3, v1))
        .map(v4 -> map4(v4, v1))
    );
```

*NB: I assumed you couldn't merge the different map functions together for some reason, like simplification of the snippet*